# Microsoft Graph console application - auth via ADAL

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a console application where the user currently has to click 'sign-in' to acquire a token for the Microsoft Graph application.

Is it possible to make this an 'auto login'?

I can see the AcquireTokenAsync method has a few overloads:

```
public static string GetAccessToken()
{
    // Create the authentication context (ADAL)
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);

    var authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphResource, 
        ClientId, RedirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, true));
    var accessToken = authenticationResult.Result.AccessToken;
    return accessToken;
}
```

I can’t create a client secret for a native app which makes it impossible to use these alternate overloads.

Can I make the application log in itself?

Comment: This question is related to auth via ADAL - not Microsoft Graph in particular

Comment: How do you want to authenticate? An user? The application itself?

Comment: Application itself - I know that if I create a web app in azure, it gives me option to create a client secret but for a native app it’s not possible

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto application itself - I know that if I create a web application in azure, it gives me option to create a client secret but for a native app it’s not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the official samples for the Azure SDK](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon), even Microsoft kind of admits their decisions are sometimes terrible:

> Enter a friendly name for the application, for example 'TodoListDaemon' and select 'Web Application and/or Web API' as the Application Type. Since this application **is a daemon and not a web application**, it doesn't have a sign-in URL, so for this field, just enter "http://TodoListDaemon".

So, as a shortcut to the docs, use the overload that asks for a `ClientCredential`:

```
var authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientCredential);
```

Comment: Thanks - are you suggesting to not make a native app? And to just use the web service app to get the token ? Native apps don’t have the option of client credentials

Comment: I am suggesting you to continue doing exactly what you are doing, but, in Azure, create a "Web Application" instead of a native one

Comment: Thanks, will try this - smart suggestion

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly correct for "daemon apps", services which run in the background. But note that you will be using a client secret/certificate, which needs to be secured. So the app must run on a machine that you own/trust.

Comment: And I agree with the confusing naming. The app type is really just a boolean in the manifest: `publicClient`, which can be true or false. A public client runs on a user's machine, a non-public client does not.

Comment: Pay particular attention to @juunas's reminder to secure the machine that is running this process. Hint: It is *not* OK to hard-code a client secret in the app's code or in a config file.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a userpasswordcredential object which inherited from usercredential, and use acquiretoken method to get the token, this gets rid of the need for the sign on authentication. Obviously this isn’t as safe as the daemon method described in the other answer.